# Trying to create an android app from a book and getting NullPointerException error at function setStartUpScreenText() on line 2

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Here is my MainActivity.java code.

package chapter.two.hello_world;

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

WorldGen earth = new WorldGen("Earth", 5973, 9.78);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();

    }  
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
    setStartUpWorldValues();
    setStartUpScreenText();


}

protected void setStartUpWorldValues(){  
earth.setPlanetColonies(1);                            
earth.setPlanetMilitary(1);                          
earth.setColonyImmigration(1000);                    
earth.setBaseProtection(100);                       
earth.turnForceFieldOn();                         

  }

  private void setStartUpScreenText(){
      TextView planetNameValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView1);
      planetNameValue.setText(earth.planetName);
    /* TextView planetMassValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView2);
      planetMassValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetMass));
      TextView planetGravityValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView3);
      planetGravityValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetGravity));
      TextView planetColoniesValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView4);
      planetColoniesValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetColonies));
      TextView planetPopulationValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView5);
      planetPopulationValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetPopulation));
      TextView planetMilitaryValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView6);
      planetMilitaryValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetMilitary));
      TextView planetBasesValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView7);
      planetBasesValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetBases));
*/    /*TextView planetForceFieldValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView8);
      planetForceFieldValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetProtection));*/

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;

        }
    }

}
```

Getting the error on setStartUpScreenText()

```
04-22 15:16:59.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1792): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 15:16:59.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1792): Process: chapter.two.hello_world, PID: 1792
04-22 15:16:59.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1792): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{chapter.two.hello_world/chapter.two.hello_world.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 15:16:59.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-22 15:16:59.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-22 15:16:59.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-22 15:16:59.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-22 15:16:59.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-22 15:16:59.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-22 15:16:59.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-22 15:16:59.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 15:16:59.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-22 15:16:59.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-22 15:16:59.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-22 15:16:59.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 15:16:59.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1792): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 15:16:59.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at chapter.two.hello_world.MainActivity.setStartUpScreenText(MainActivity.java:44)
04-22 15:16:59.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at chapter.two.hello_world.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
04-22 15:16:59.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-22 15:16:59.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-22 15:16:59.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-22 15:16:59.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1792):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Do you have a TextView in your `activity_main.xml` with an id of `dataView1`?

Comment: planetNameValue is null because it's in fragment_main.xml. The easiest way to resolve the problem is to cut the layout from fragment_main.xml and paste it in activity_main.xml

Comment: @dcharms notice that he called setContentView() twice. I'm not sure if this works.

Comment: Good catch. In that case @Onik, he is already doing what you suggested by inflating the Fragment layout for his Activity.

Comment: @Henry Hu is right. Comment the line setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Answer (score 0):

Probably the TextView planetNameValue is null because R.id.dataview1 does not exist in the layout fragment_main.